# Caching objects locally for reuse (Parse.com / Backbone)

Tags: caching, backbone.js, local-storage, marionette, parse-platform

Currently using a setup that follows: [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/), [Parse](http://parse.com), [Require](http://requirejs.org/), and [Marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette).

I've found through my application that I often need to reuse objects I've already pulled down from Parse.

Parse already does this through `Parse.User.current()`, However it would be great to store other entities locally rather than retrieving them over and over again.

Does anyone have any suggestions in terms of good practices or libraries to use for caching these objects locally or would having global variables that hold the information while the application runs be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Parse JavaScript SDK is open source, so you could look at the implementation of `Parse.User.current` and `Parse.User._saveCurrentUser`.  Maybe you could do something similar.  http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.1.11.js